# Using graph traversal to test is a graph is a perfect binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

When given an undirected graph G represented by an adjacency list how can you use a DFS to see if that graph is a perfect binary tree?

I have been able to identify edge cases: such as using the fact that for a depth D you need 2^n-1 nodes you can can work out the max depth using a logarithm and if that isn't whole you know you don't have a perfect tree but I cant think of an efficient way of using the adjacency list and DFS to test.

Comment: you could have a counter dictionary where you track the number of nodes in each level. Also have a set that keeps track of visited nodes. As you do your dfs keep track of the depth and add new nodes to their respective levels. At the end, check whether each level has the appropriate number of nodes.

Comment: The hardest part is figuring out which node is the root of this perfect binary tree. If you have a graph which is a tree in the graph-sense, then you can pick any node as a root, and you'll get a tree in the parent-and-children-sense. But in your case, only one of the possible roots will result in a perfect binary tree.

Comment: I would suggest an algorithm in two parts: First, identify up to one candidate root; then, check that with this root, you have a perfect binary tree.

Comment: PS: For future questions, consider asking on [the computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com) rather than on stackoverflow. You're likely to get better answers over there for the more theoretical questions, and better answers over here for the more programming-oriented questions.

Comment: @Stef the root is the only vertex with degree 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a perfect binary tree that is not empty, with  nodes, we have these properties:

- The number of nodes  is one less than a power of 2, i.e. ℎ=log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub>(+1) is integer. =2<sup>ℎ</sup>−1
- The number of edges is −1
- There are no nodes with more than 3 neighbors.
- When  > 1, there is (only) one node with exactly 2 neighbors: it is the root.
- When  > 1, the leaves of the tree have only one neighbor: there are 2<sup>ℎ-1</sup> of them.
- The distance between the root and any leaf is ℎ−1.

These properties can be checked one after the other. Once you have identified the root, you can perform a traversal to check the distance property. Either with DFS or BFS.

Comment: If you have identified the root and are going to perform a traversal, then only the property "every node at depth < h-1 has exactly two children, and every node at depth h-1 is a leaf" needs to be checked.

Comment: Yes, but a check like for the number of edges can be worth doing, as it is very cheap and can lead to a quick exit without doing the traversal or even building the adjacency list. Also the check for more than 3 neighbors can be done while building the adjacency list, and lead to a quicker exit.

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is empty, or has only one vertex, then return true.

Otherwise, check to make sure the graph is connected and acyclic.

Then, if it's a perfect binary tree, there must be only one vertex of degree 2. That's the root.  Let `a` and `b` be its two children.  Then:

```
let depthA = depthIfPerfect(a, root);
let depthB = depthIfPerfect(b, root);
return depthA == depthB && depthA >=0
```

where:

```
depthIfPerfect(node, parent):

    if degree(node) == 1:
        return 1;
    if degree(node) != 3:
        return -1; //not perfect

    let a and b be the neighbors that aren't parent

    let depthA = depthIfPerfect(a, node);
    let depthB = depthIfPerfect(b, node);
    
    if (depthA != depthB || depthA < 0):
        return -1: //not perfect
    return depthA+1;
```

You can mix the check for connectedness and acyclicity into this traversal if you like.